# isnumeric(textbox.value) and manipulating textbox.values into and out to percentages

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am attempting to "assist" the user of the text input box on my userform in entering percentages.

As of now, my input box converts any input into percentage form. This means that typing "6" would convert the value to 600%. As seen below

databaseViewer is the list (which gets data off a worksheet) that the inputbox populates from

```
Sub pctTextInput(header As String, inputbox As Object)

    If IsNull(databaseViewer.Value) Or inputbox.Text = "" Then
        GoTo 0
    Else
        With Cells(databaseViewerGetSelectedRow, getApplicableColumn(header))
         .Value = inputbox.Text
         .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If
0:
inputbox.Value = ""
End Sub
```

My problem now is that I am trying to

1. Do a validate case with the textbox user input for numeric values, if not return an error

I actually tried the isnumeric(textbox.value) on the above but it always returns false EVEN on a cell that has a % value in it already

2. simplify the user input process so that instead of having to type 0.6 to get 60%; the person only needs to type 60 to get 60% (i.e. more intuitive.)

For this I attempted to do something like this, which returns type mismatch even if i try to CDbl(inputbox.text) or Clng(inputbox.text), which leads me to believe that I am not educated on the format of textboxes, which I had assumed to be type String.

> ```
>     Dim x As Long
>     x = inputbox.Text / 100
>     inputbox.Text = x
> ```

EDIT: Updated with new code that still returns type mismatch based on the comments by @urdearboy

```
Sub pctTextInputDUPLICATED(header As String, textbox As Object) 'this TEXTbox will trigger on value change

Dim userEntryOrDefault As Variant
Dim modifiedUserEntryOrDefault As Variant
userEntryOrDefault = textbox.Value

    If IsNull(databaseViewer.Value) Or textbox.Text = "" Then
        textbox.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(userEntryOrDefault) Then
        textbox.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf userEntryOrDefault <> Cells(databaseViewerGetSelectedRow, getApplicableColumn(header)) Then
        modifiedUserEntryOrDefault = Format(userEntryOrDefault / 100, "percent")
    Else
        With Cells(databaseViewerGetSelectedRow, getApplicableColumn(header))
         .Value = textbox.Text
         .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If


End Sub
Sub userform1_Activate() 'populate with cell value if any

    With textbox
        .Value = Format(Cells(databaseViewerGetSelectedRow, getApplicableColumn("Adequacy")), "0.0%")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: application.inputbox (not inputbox) allows you to specify numbers only.

Comment: @Jeeped Hi I am not exactly certain as to the implication of your comment... I dimmed it inputBox as Object to make it easier for me to manipulate the textbox.

Comment: What line throws code

Comment: @eeeccc17 Which line does throw the mismatch error?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ 

HI Both,

I managed to get 2 seperate unideal situation

    `ElseIf Not IsNumeric(userEntryOrDefault) Then
        Textbox.Value = ""
        Exit Sub`

This line if left in the procedure returns NOT numeric, which is untrue as the cell it points to is a value of 60%

If i remove the above line then

    `ElseIf userEntryOrDefault <> Cells(databaseViewerGetSelectedRow, getApplicableColumn(header)) Then
        modifiedUserEntryOrDefault = Format(userEntryOrDefault / 100, "percent")`

returns type mismatch

Comment: Please debug your code (go through it step by step using F8) and tell us the values of `textbox.Value` and `databaseViewerGetSelectedRow` and `getApplicableColumn(header)`

Comment: textbox.value = nothing appears when I hover over it, but userEntryorDefault inherited "174.0%" from it 

The last 2 are 30 and 21 respectively

Comment: @Pᴇʜ `modifiedUserEntryOrDefault = Format(userEntryOrDefault / 100, "percent")  returns the type mismatch`

Comment: Well I would check at first `If userEntryOrDefault Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` or something to ensure it is not `Nothing`. Second: If `userEntryorDefault = "174.0%"` this is a string and you cannot divide a string by 100, that will give the type mismatch.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ 

For `ElseIf userEntryOrDefault Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` I actually got an error that an Object is required.

For the second comment that it is a string, is there a way to convert it into a Long value? I have tried `clng(Textbox.Value)` which still returns type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have all the inputs to run your code as is, I just did a mock up to address the questions you had and you can apply the logic to your code as needed.

1) To test for a number you can use `Not IsNumeric()`

2) To convert the input to a %, just divide the input by 100 and then convert THAT 
into a percent. I dimmed a new variable (MyNewNum) to do this.

3) You should avoid the `GoTo` method whenever possible

```
Sub pctTextInput()

Dim MyNum As Variant, MyNewNum As Variant
MyNum = inputbox("Number Input", "Please Enter a Number")

    If Not IsNumeric(MyNum) Or MyNum = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter A Number, My Dear User", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox MyNum
        MyNewNum = Format(MyNum / 100, "percent")
        MsgBox MyNewNum
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I cant get this to work .. I am still getting type mismatch.

I think i must have confused you all with the "Dim inputbox as object" This is a textbox as found in a user form.

i cant seem to copy the code in here with the limited characters so I added my new code above

Answer (score 0):

[Application.Inputbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel) has options that Inputbox doesn't have. One of these options forces numeric input.

```
sub getNumber()

    dim n as variant

    n = Application.Inputbox(prompt:="get a number", title:="give me a number", type:=1)

    if n <> "False" then
        debug.print n
    else
        debug.print "you cancelled"
    end if

end sub
```

Comment: This is a textbox as seen in a Userform. I must have confused you all by "dim INPUTBOX as Object"

So sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
val(textbox.value)
```